# k6 starter pod in error : sh: curl: not found

Tags: k6

pod/k6-sample-starter-5vct7                          0/1     Error       0          4m48s

kubectl logs job.batch/k6-sample-starter -n k6-operator-system
Found 6 pods, using pod/k6-sample-starter-5vct7
sh: curl: not found
sh: curl: not found

Here is my k6 kind custom resource

---

apiVersion: k6.io/v1alpha1
kind: K6
metadata:
name: k6-sample
spec:
parallelism: 1
script:
configMap:
name: k6-test
file: test.js
runner:
image: XXX/grafana/k6:0.48.0
tolerations:

```
affinity:
```

starter:
image: XXX/grafana/k6:0.48.0
tolerations:

```
affinity:
```

Answer (score 0):

found the solution
custom image for starter and runner I was using is wrong image.

Use runner and starter tags

docker pull ghcr.io/grafana/k6-operator:runner-v0.0.13

docker pull ghcr.io/grafana/k6-operator:starter-v0.0.13